# How can I prevent Cargo from automatically trying to download a newer version of the compiler?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I need to compile an older version of Parity which only compiles with version 1.28 of the Rust compiler. To install the older version, I did this:

```
rustup.sh -y --default-toolchain 1.28.0
```

This seems to work:

```
root@2afa3b8dc256:/build# cargo --version
cargo 1.28.0 (96a2c7d16 2018-07-13)
root@2afa3b8dc256:/build# rustc --version
rustc 1.28.0 (9634041f0 2018-07-30)
```

When I try to compile the project, it immediately tries to download a new version of the compiler:

```
root@2afa3b8dc256:/parity# cargo build --all
info: syncing channel updates for 'stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu'
320.1 KiB / 320.1 KiB (100 %) 271.0 KiB/s ETA:   0 s                
info: latest update on 2018-11-08, rust version 1.30.1 (1433507eb 2018-11-07)
info: downloading component 'rustc'
```

How can I prevent Cargo from doing that?

Comment: Is there a `rust-toolchain` file in the directory?

Comment: Oh; is that a new feature? Didn't even knew this was a thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the used toolchain version for a specific directory by using `rustup override`. For example:

```
rustup override set 1.28.0
```